# WPF application loses touch capability

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, touchscreen

I am developing a WPF application (.NET Framework 4.5) and I have a strange behavior.

The application is meant to run on a Windows 8.0 with a Elo Touch screen (elotouch.com).

When running the application in Release mode, on the production machine, the application randomly stop accepting touch events.

The application did not froze (it's still actionnable with a mouse), and the other applications and the system still respond to touch events.

Any idea where this issue could come from ?
Windows ? The Framework ? My code ?

**Edit :** Reducing the screen resolution fixes it, but I'd rather have my application running in high resolution

Comment: have you found any workarounds for this ?
I've got a similar scenario were in high resolution touch works badly.
but only when the visual tree is very large.

Comment: @eranotzap Upgrading to Windows 8.1 fixed the problem for me

Comment: wow that's a useful  piece of info, 10x .

Comment: I'm sorry that my answer doesn't suit your need, but you asked me if I've found a workaround for a problem I had last year. I did not say that I have a solution for your particular issue, just how mine got solved.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't mean to sound cynical. it really is helpfull.
I got one system with windows 7 and one with windows 8 .

Comment: lol after reading my comment again it does sound rather stingful

Comment: in your situation did this behavior occur only if the visual tree was very large ?

Comment: I don't remember well the details as this was a project that is now a year old, but it was, graphically speaking, quite a simple application so I don't think the visual tree was very large.

Comment: Having very similar problems. Anyone find a solution? For whatever reason the Manipulation events are no longer being called, it goes into this mode randomly.

Comment: Using WPF .NET 4.5.1 + Win 8.1 with a touch screen tablet

Comment: Well, same issue on NET 6 at year 2022, did anyone find workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to Windows 8.1 fixes the problem.
It's a constraining solution but it seems to work for people with this issue.

Comment: Running on Windows 10 IoT and have the same problem.